# ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED on heroku app

Tags: heroku, dns, algolia

I'm trying to integrate Algolia Search onto my heroku node app. Everything seems to be working fine on my localhost, but after deploying to heroku, all my algolia endpoints seem to return ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED.

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: what endpoint are you using?

Comment: you can also contact algolia support https://www.algolia.com/doc/faq/basics/how-to-contact-support/